# Use socks proxy in terminal

Tags: ubuntu, http-proxy, tor, socks

I am using selektor, which is similar to vidalia tor bundle. The default settings, use safe socks with port number 9054. It is fine and when I set the firefox proxy to "use system proxy", I can access blocked website, e. g. www.torproject.org

As I enter `wget http://torproject.org`, that will not use the vpn established.  What can I do, in oder to make it work? I don't want to use a prefix such as `foo wget www.torproject.org`. Is there any way to define a `socks_proxy` variable? I see `http_proxy` which is not appropriate here. Any idea?